# How to ignore change in line using AWK

Tags: sql, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am writing a shell script in which I need to pull out the names of the table in which data is inserted.
So if the sql script contains a statement such as "Insert into *table_name*", the script should fetch out the table name.

This is what I am using

`awk '{IGNORECASE = 1} /INSERT INTO/ && !a[$3]++{print $3}' $check_in_script  >> $TBL_LST
 awk '{IGNORECASE = 1} /UPDATE/ && !a[$2]++{print $2}' $check_in_script  >> $TBL_LST`

This is running fine but there are cases when the scripts have a line break between the insert into and the table name and I need to add a case for that as well.

```
insert into 
table_name
```

How do I make sure that even if there is a change in line, the awk statement fetches out the table name

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for sharing your efforts in form of code in your question. Please do add samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: [edit] your question to show a few lines of truly representative sample input/output with the text you want to match in context among other text you do and don't want to match.

Comment: @yutivee : How do you deal with a situtation where the words _insert into_ are not part of the SQL command proper, but part of a string, for instance `update table  set text = 'insert into'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can used sed to remove new line in input file.

`sed  '/Insert/I{N;s/\n//g}'`

Demo :

```
$echo 'insert into 
table_name'  
insert into 
table_name
$echo 'insert into 
table_name'  |  sed  '/Insert/I{N;s/\n//g}'
insert into table_name
$
```

Comment: Hey Digvijay, Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if we can do something in the awk statements I already have because modifying the underlying file would not be permitted in many cases.